# Does the advantage reroll of Elven Accuracy only apply to the ability you increased?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, advantage-and-disadvantage

The [Elven Accuracy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/elven-accuracy) feat, from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (pg. 74), says this:

> - Increase your **Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma** score by 1, to a maximum of 20
> - Whenever you have advantage on an attack roll using **Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma**, you can reroll one of the dice once.

My question is, if I increase, say, Dexterity by 1 using this feat, would the other benefit of this feat (about rerolling a die when you have advantage) only apply when making an attack roll using Dexterity, or could I use this with any of these abilities?

Given the fact that they have the same wording, and that clearly you are only meant to increase one ability score as per the first bullet, I wonder if that "ties you" to that ability for the second bullet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Elven Accuracy applies to all the attack rolls.

The two bullet points are independent. Consider the wording of the *Resilient* feat, where all of the effects apply to only one ability score:

> **Choose one ability score**. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - Increase the **chosen** ability score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You gain proficiency in saving throws using the **chosen** ability.

Emphasis mine. If the intention of *Elven Accuracy* was that the second point only applied to one ability score, it would have been worded similarly to *Resilient*. The second point of *Elven Accuracy* makes no mention to the ability score increased in the first point, so its benefit applies to all listed abilities.

Comment: Nice comparison to Resilient, this reasoning makes sense to me. +1

Comment: I'd agree that Rules As Written agrees with you, But that the rules as written are likely errata that should be checked by wotc.

Comment: @RyanLeach: Why do you think they'd be errata-ed? When the two abilities are tied together, it's usually because it's for spellcasting, or the Resilient case, where it's giving you a boost to two directly related things. Elven Accuracy is just a typical half-ASI, it gives a boost to a choice of one stat, and *also* gives a loosely related benefit. It's not like it's particularly exploitable; most characters can only use at most two of those attack stats effectively (Dex + one spellcasting ability); it's not some *huge* benefit to extend it to additional stats like it would be with Resilient.